# regex: extracting alphanumeric sequences delimited by a "-" (minus) character

Tags: python-3.x, regex

String:

```
text = '<script src="https://mytest.com/abcdefg12-hijklmno34.js"></script>'
```

I'd like to extract these two alphanumeric values delimited by "-":

```
regex = '??????'
m = re.split(regex, text)    
print(m)
```

desired output output:

```
[
'abcdefg12',
'hijklmno34
]
```

What's the most elegant regex should I be using for this?

Comment: You could use `r'/([a-z\d.]+)-([a-z\d.]+)(?=[^.])` with the case-indifferent flag set. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/kBnZR9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myarray = re.compile('\w+(?=-)|(?<=-)\w+').findall(text)
```

Comment: Given +1. Good answer

Comment: @bigbounty not bad for a java guy, eh? :)

Comment: Haha, yeah. Learning from you guys

Comment: What about `mytest.com/abcdefg12-/abc/-hijklmno34.js`?

Comment: do you think this pattern will work  `/(?=\w+\-\w+)(\w+)|(?<=\w\-)(\w+)/`

Comment: @CarySwoveland what about it? this regex suits OP's purpose well.  your example is out of scope.

Comment: @Sven.hig yes, and your regex more precisely fits the example input.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [54]: text = '<script src="https://mytest.com/abcdefg12-hijklmno34.js"></script>'

In [55]: m = re.search("com\/(.*)\.", text)

In [56]: m[1]
Out[56]: 'abcdefg12-hijklmno34'

In [57]: m[1].split("-")
Out[57]: ['abcdefg12', 'hijklmno34']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern `/(?=\w+\-\w+)(\w+)|(?<=\w\-)(\w+)/g`